# Why didn't Megatron kill Starscream in G1?

Tags: transformers

I've been rewatching Season 1 of G1, and Starscream is constantly undermining Megatron.  He is so indiscreet about it though... he'll openly discuss his plans to mutiny against Megatron.  Megatron frequently threatens to take out Starscream, but never seems to do so.

Why didn't Megatron ever kill Starscream?

Comment: I've little to back this up, but I'd be willing to bet that it was because cartoon characters just weren't killed off back then. To my memory, Optimus was the first major character killed in a cartoon series franchise, and it was received so negatively that they had to change the ending of the GI Joe movie in post production (Duke was originally supposed to die.)

Comment: @phantom42 Granted, Starscream was then killed off five minutes later by ---Megatron--- Galvatron. Also granted that this comment is two years late.

Comment: It bears mentioning that Starscream is listed as the leader of the Seekers (the jet transformers) and the Seekers made up half of Megatron's forces in G1. Could be, he didn't want the other Seekers to rebel

Comment: @phantom42 - By the end of the macross saga in Robotech every character in the whole show except maybe 7 is dead. That was on the same time as Transformers, albeit of non-american origins. It still played in the US. And it was awesome because it was willing to do what no other cartoons did.

Comment: ... also, the majority of the population of earth dies in the force of arms episode. Plus the crews of the 4 million ships in space.

Answer (score 9):

From the [Transformers Universe](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0871352966) book:

> Megatron overlooks the potential threat Starscream represents for one very good reason: Starscream is very good at his job.

Online entry: [Starscream](http://www.seibertron.com/comics/universe/original/index.php?tf_id=starscream).

Comment: And it also seems that promotion by regicide is an acceptable practice among the 'cons.

Answer (score 5):

### Megatron simply can't afford to be without Starscream

At this stage in the Transformers canon, the Deceptions are fairly few in number and substantially outnumbered by the Autobots. Compare the list of troops on both sides [here](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/More_than_Meets_the_Eye,_Part_1).

The Decepticons are typically outnumbered in G1 Season 1 but compensate in other ways, such as with their ability to fly.

[image: The Decepticons fly past as the Autobots fire at them from the ground]

### However...

Megatron, newly reformatted as **Galvatron**, [finally killed Starscream in the 1986 animated movie](https://moviemorgue.fandom.com/wiki/Starscream_(G1)), following Starscream's treacherous usurption of Megatron.

[image: Galvatron, in his Space Cannon mode, blasts Starscream]

Answer (score 2):

The main reason behind this is Megatron's own ability to perceive the attributes of Starscream. Perhaps he sees a little of himself in Starscream, if not the physical part, at least the "cunning part" definitely. This prompts him to reconsider his decision of killing Starscream; Starscream may  inadvertently come up with a useful idea to demolish the Autobots, which Megatron then can use at his own discretion.

Having said that, Megatron is in a dilemma. He is constantly toying with the idea of either having Starscream terminated or banished. He seems just not able to make up his mind, due to his past association with Starscream. Also, due to the same reason he may think, that Starscream will never be able to outwit him.